# Focus change on dynamically generated entries of CollectionView

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am displaying n number of entries dynamically using CollectionView to capture text using Xamarin.Forms. I would like to shift focus from one entry to another entry by pressing Next button in the keyboard for both Android and iOS. I referred the article https://iwritecodesometimes.net/2018/06/25/building-a-next-entry-effect-for-ios-and-android-in-xamarin-forms/ and am almost there. The only difficulty I am facing is on how to wire the entries sequentially one to another dynamically. I am thinking of getting the references of these entries and do the needful but I couldn't do so as this is dynamically generated. I am not sure what would be the parent control for these entries so that we can iterate these entries references and map one entry to another. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to add the code for this, which would help us understand the situation better

Comment: Do your solution demand the use of a collectionView? It only makes sense using a collectionView if the cells need to be virtualized - and if this is not the case, you could consider generating views in a stacklayout, and in this way you have a better idea of where your focus is right now (what index), and what is next.

Comment: Hi , you can have a try with connecting them by items of `CollectionView` .Each item of `CollectionView` assign an ID , then you also can use ID of Items to connect them between `Entry` in CollectionView.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I would like to know how to connect them with classIDs. That is the problem here.

Comment: @Ramesh Where you define the classID , could you show some code .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT We can have class ID like <Entry ClassID={Binding IDNumber} .../>

Comment: @Ramesh Okey , `ClassID` bind data from `IDNumber` , then I think you can use `IDNumber` of ViewModel to change focus when return key down . This requires some processing in the ViewModel.